# Is it OK to reference an accepted answer and explain why it is not the correct/best option?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Imagine this scenario

1. You see a question of a new / low rep user where you identify a design problem
2. You answer a question explaining the problem and redefining the design
3. Another answer appears recommending an ugly but working workaround that ignores design problem.
4. The other answer is accepted by OP

Is it ok to quote / reference / link the answer to explain why is wrong when is already accepted?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "reference"? Just add a comment, no?

Comment: Do you mean *"can I refer to other answers in my answer"* then: yes, of course.

Comment: @jonrsharpe not exactly, I know I can do it... but... it is appropiate when is an already accepted answer?

Comment: That depends on what you're going to write! If you can make constructive suggestions for improvement, I don't see there being a problem - just because the OP solved their problem using that answer doesn't make it sacrosanct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok to quote / reference / link the answer to explain why is wrong when is already accepted?

You mean inside your answer, to explain why it is wrong? Totally. (Politely, of course - and never try to get the OP to change the accept mark. There's no point.)

The accept mark doesn't change that it's a bad answer, and your input will likely be valuable to future generations.