# Clipping of text in meta comments

Tags: bug, comments, design

Commenting [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328901/is-it-ok-to-reference-an-accepted-answer-and-explain-why-it-is-not-the-correct-b) I've seen a clipping issue. Is this a bug? Is it already reported?

Tested using:

- `Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m (64-bit)` in a Windows 7 Amazon Workspace Machine
- `Google Chrome Versión 49.0.2623.75 m` in a Windows 7 regular machine.

[image]

Comment: Works fine with me, which browser and version are you using?

Comment: @Draken updated question, Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m (64-bit)

Comment: Same as me, except for the 64bit. Can anyone else reproduce?

Comment: Looks fine for me as well.

Comment: I think I need glasses. Where is this clipping problem? Is it that the grey background of your username slightly overlaps the comment text?

Comment: @Gimby yes, that slightly overlap is called clipping.

Comment: I did not ask for an explanation about the term clipping, I was confirming that it was that tiny tiny overlap and not somewhere I was not looking. Being specific is a good thing. I see it somewhat on Chrome on a Mac, it might be related to the style of font.

Comment: @Gimby, maybe... not problem of the zoom at least...  And yes.. is tiny and does not disturb, that's why I ask if it's a bug, because is a really minor issue and looking at the comments, it must be localized in few OS / browser combinations.